# Node.js config file for mysql DB

Tags: mysql, node.js, config

I have a small issue when setting up my config file. I'm sure this is something **simple** but I don't see what is the problem.

I have my config file config.js under config/config.js

```
var databaseOptions = {
    host     : 'localhost',
    database : 'test',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'root',
    port     : '8889'
};
module.exports = databaseOptions;
```

And then I use it in my model:

```
var config = require('../config/config.js');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection(config.databaseOptions);
```

But it doesn't work ...
Instead I get an error : *TypeError: Cannot read property 'host' of undefined*

I also tried like this :

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
          host     : config.databaseOptions.host,
          database : config.databaseOptions.database,
          user     : config.databaseOptions.user,
          password : config.databaseOptions.password,
          port     : config.databaseOptions.port
});
```

... but I still get an undefined error.

Any idea ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are exporting `databaseOptions` directly so you just need:

```
var databaseOptions = require('../config/config.js');
var connection = mysql.createConnection(databaseOptions);
```

If you want to use config.databaseOptions, you need to export:

```
var databaseOptions = {
    host     : 'localhost',
    database : 'test',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'root',
    port     : '8889'
};
module.exports = {databaseOptions: databaseOptions} ;
```

**or**

```
module.exports.databaseOptions = {
  host     : 'localhost',
  database : 'test',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'root',
  port     : '8889'
};
```

Then you can use:

```
var config = require('../config/config.js');
var connection = mysql.createConnection(config.databaseOptions);
```

The second way will be more flexible if you have more than one object you want to export from `config`.

Comment: Great! It works! I’ll go to the second option you you showed. I have several objets in my config file. Thanks!